# How can I set a default status code (200) or return another status code?

Tags: php, frameworks

I'm looking for help on how to incorporate a response class to return HTTP response codes. I'm a novice PHP user and using this to improve my coding skills and understanding of frameworks. Should I bring the response class at `$app->run()` or in the Kernel.php file at `$this-router-dispatch()`?

The default response code should be 200, unless I specify a different value such as 404, 405, 500, etc...

I added comments in the files to show which status codes should be returned.

Here are my files:

**index.php**

```
$app = new Kernel();

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/routes/web.php';

$app->run();
```

**Kernel.php**

```
class Kernel
{
    public static Kernel $app;
    public Request $request;
    public Response $response;
    public Router $router;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$app = $this;
        $this->request = new Request();
        $this->response = new Response();
        $this->router = new Router();
    }

    public function run(): void
    {
        $this->router->dispatch($this->request->path(), $this->request->method());
    }
}
```

**Request.php**

```
class Request
{
    public function method(): string
    {
        if (!in_array($method = strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']), ['GET', 'POST'], true))
        {
            // This should return a 405 response code.
        }

        return $method;
    }

    public function path(): false|int|array|string|null
    {
        return parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH);
    }
}
```

**Router.php**

```
class Router
{
    protected array $routes = [];

    public function dispatch($path, $method): void
    {
        // route found
        // return controller and status 200

        // route not found
        // return 405 status code
    }
}
```

**Response.php**

```
class Response
{
    public const HTTP_OK = 200;
    public const HTTP_NOT_FOUND = 404;
    public const HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED = 405;

    // Not sure what to do here.
    public function setStatusCode()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main use of the Response class is in your Controllers, and after dispatching router.
First, you need something like a static method called make to create an object for you (factory pattern).

```php
// Response

    public static function make(): static
    {
        return new static();
    }
```

In your controller, you can go with something like this:

```php
// A Controller
return Response::make()->setBody($pc->toArray())->setStatusCode(201);
```

In the above example, you see an extra method called `setBody` so each response has a body.

The response class must represent an HTTP response, so you need to add `body` and `statusCode` as class properties.

Your setters in the Response class must be method chaining to help users by calling them unorder.

Here's a full example of Response class:

```php
<?php

namespace Core;

class Response
{
    public const HTTP_OK = 200; 
    public const HTTP_NOT_FOUND = 404; 
    public const HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED = 405;

    private string $body = '';
    private int $statusCode = 200;

    public static function make(): static
    {
        return new static();
    }

    public function setStatusCode(int $statusCode): static
    {
        $this->statusCode = $statusCode;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatusCode(): int
    {
        return $this->statusCode;
    }

    public function setBody($body): static
    {
        if (is_array($body)) {
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            $body = json_encode($body);
        }

        $this->body = $body;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBody(): string
    {
        return $this->body;
    }
}
```

After this, we can complete the `run` method and return our response by simply setting the status code from response and echoing the body:

```php
    public function run(): void
    {
        $response = $this->router->dispatch($this->request->path(), $this->request->method());
        http_response_code($response->getStatusCode());
        echo $response->getBody();
    }
```

Here's an important note: Router dispatch must return the response which it receives from the controller.

Here's a router class example that you can use to understand what dispatch should look like:

```php
<?php

namespace Core;

use DI\DependencyException;
use DI\NotFoundException;
use Exception;

class Router
{
    protected static array $routes = [];

    public function __construct(protected Request $request, protected Response $response)
    {
        include_once __DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php';
    }

    public static function get($path, $callback): void
    {
        self::$routes['get'][$path] = $callback;
    }

    public static function post($path, $callback): void
    {
        self::$routes['post'][$path] = $callback;
    }

    public static function put($path, $callback): void
    {
        self::$routes['put'][$path] = $callback;
    }

    public static function patch($path, $callback): void
    {
        self::$routes['patch'][$path] = $callback;
    }

    public static function delete($path, $callback): void
    {
        self::$routes['delete'][$path] = $callback;
    }

    /**
     * @throws DependencyException
     * @throws NotFoundException
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function resolve(): Response
    {
        $path = $this->request->getPath();
        $method = $this->request->getMethod();
        $callback = self::$routes[$method][$path] ?? false;

        if ($callback === false) {
            return $this->response->setBody('Not Found')->setStatusCode(404);
        }

        if (is_array($callback)) {
            $fn = Application::$container->get($callback[0]);
            array_shift($callback);
            $callback = array_merge([$fn], $callback);
        }

        $response = call_user_func($callback, $this);

        if (! $response instanceof Response) {
            throw new Exception('You must return a Response object');
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

I used [auto wiring](https://php-di.org/) in the Router to make creating an object of controllers easier, and if sometimes I need to inject something in the method (like request or route model binging)

Comment: Can you elaborate on this part "// A Controller
return Response::make()->setBody($pc->toArray())->setStatusCode(201);"

Comment: In short, No. You can have that response object in your Application class and pass it to the Router next to Request. The purpose of the response injected into the Router is for when you don't have a controller, and basically, you don't have a response, So you use this injected response to return a 404 or 405.

Comment: You need to return a Response in controller methods. In Laravel and some other frameworks, you can just return a string, and it will generate a response, but for easiness of your MVC framework, you can say that all controllers must return a Response.
Response::make is factory method pattern.
in body, we set an array you can think of as a simple associative array. and then we set the status code.
That's the method chaining that I told. The call order of `SetBody` and `setStatusCode` is not important.

Comment: Let me clarify, if I have a view I want to send to the controller, would I add that in the setBody()? I'm not sure what $pc->toArray() is.  The other stuff I do understand.

Comment: For views, you won't use `setBody` directly. You can create a helper method like `render`. It resolves and renders your view. It will return a Response, which sets the Response's body.
Or you can add a method named `render` to the Response class, which will do the same job.
The purpose of `render` method is to find your view files and get the HTML.
The body is what you want to show you can replace `$pc->toArray()` with an HTML code. My use case was RestAPI.